# Creating a Reducer Class for ReactJS + Redux

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am attempting to reduce the amount of code I use for the reducers and actions in a ReactJS-Redux application and I am running into some trouble figuring out why the data loaded in a read action populated BOTH reducer keys in the store.

reducer.js;

```
export class ReducerClass{
    constructor(){
        this.initialState = {data:[],record:{},loading:false,editmode:0};
    }    
    reducer = (state = this.initialState,action) =>{
        let newState = {...state};
        switch(action.type){
            case "_READ":
                newState.data = action.value;
                newState.loading = false;                     
                return(newState);                
            default:
                return(newState);
        }
    }
}
```

action.js:

```
export class ActionClass{
    constructor(tablename){
        this.tablename = tablename;        
    }
    actionRead = (params) => (dispatch) => {        
        let query = params ? toQueryString(params) : "";
        let url = this.tablename + (query ? "?" + query : "");
        dbFetch(url, (data) => dispatch({ type: "_READ", value: data }));
    }
    mapStateToProps = (state) => {
        let dataTable = state[this.tablename];
        return { data: dataTable.data, record: dataTable.record, loading: dataTable.loading, editmode: dataTable.editmode };
    }
    mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
        return {
            read: (params) => dispatch(this.actionRead(params))
        };
    }    
}
```

store.js:

```
import { ReducerClass } from './reducer.js';
let cusdata = new ReducerClass();
let emldata = new ReducerClass();
let rootReducer = combineReducers({
     cusdata: cusdata.reducer,
     emldata: cusdata.reducer
});
export const Store = createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(thunk));
```

Obviously I did not include all the imports as most of them are implicit.
Declaring the connectors in (lets say) a grid component:

```
cusDataGridConnect = new ActionClass("cusdata");
export default connect(cusDataGridConnect.mapStateToProps, cusDataGridConnect.mapDispatchToProps)(CusDataGrid);
```

And For the other grid component:

```
const emlDataGridConnect = new ActionClass("emldata")
export default connect(emlDataGridConnect.mapStateToProps, emlDataGridConnect.mapDispatchToProps)(EmlDataGrid);
```

The problem I am running into is when I perform a read on the cusdata grid, the data poplated in both store keys (populated for cusdata AND emldata).  Is there anyone who can help with creating a Reducer and Action type class?  Most (if not all) of my operations will do the exact same thing and I am attempting to reduce on code duplication.  Thanks for any help.

Comment: I would say the issue is that both `ActionClass` instances generate the same type of action (`_READ`), and both reducers listen to this type of actions. You need to provide an arg to both your action and reducer creators (you already do with your action creator: `tablename`) that you use to construct action types that are specific.

Comment: Nicolas, that was definitely the problem.  Thanks for your help.  Please post this as an answer so I can close and upvote.

Comment: Done. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say the issue is that both ActionClass instances generate the same type of action (_READ), and both reducers listen to this type of actions. You need to provide an arg to both your action and reducer creators (you already do with your action creator: tablename) that you use to construct action types that are specific.